# Unable to convert unicode to string in python getting error

Tags: python, excel, string, unicode, unicode-string

I'm reading a column from an excel file into a list as follows:

```
import xlrd
import openpyxl
book = xlrd.open_workbook("English corpus.xlsx")
sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)


data=[]
for row_index in xrange(1, sheet.nrows): # skip heading row
    timestamp, text, header, transporter, device_type = sheet.row_values(row_index, end_colx=5)
    print (text)
    data.append(text)
```

But with the the elements in the `data` list are of type "unicode". I tried doing the following to convert them to string:

```
[x.encode('UTF8') for x in data]
```

But then it gives me the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

then I tried doing the following:

```
[str(x).encode('UTF8') for x in data]
```

that's giving me the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe9' in position 176: ordinal not in range(128)
```

OR:
If you could tell me how I could read from the excel column into the list not as unicode elements but normal string. Thanks

Comment: It seems the attributes are of type `int`, not `unicode`...

Comment: `unicode` is a string. Unless you need ascii for something you probably don't need to convert it at all.

Comment: when I do type(x), I get <type, 'unicode'>. But I want <type, 'str'>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last error is coming from `str(x)`; if you use `[unicode(x).encode('UTF8') for x in data]`, you will avoid that error.

Comment: that removes the error, but the list elements still remain in unicode type only rather than being in string type.

Comment: `data = [unicode(x).encode('UTF8') for x in data]` will replace the old list with the new.